# Height / Bottom alignement of nodes in forest environment

Tags: forest, trees

I have a problem with the configuration of the height of the nodes in the forest environment.

As you can see, the middle child is not aligned at the bottom with the rest of the child nodes.

[image]

This is my MWE.

I Need to be able to control the child nodes further down, hence the `tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()}`

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        edge label={node[above,fill=white, yshift=2mm, font=\footnotesize]{100\%}},
        fill=red!100,
        l sep=3em,
        s sep=5pt,
        minimum height=3em,
        minimum width=9em, 
        text width=9em,
        text centered,
        text=white,
        rounded corners, 
        tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
        }, 
        forked edges,
%   Indsæt her: 
[Company A \\ ~\\ Finland
    [Company X \\ ~\\ Denmark]
    [Company Y \\ ~\\ Norway]
    [Company Z \\ ~\\ Sweden]
]
\end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
```

I concluded that it must be the "y" i "Norway" that causes the problem, because when I remove it, it aligns. I tried changing the minimum height of the nodes, but that didn't help.

When I use the following as my for tree, the problem isn't there, but then I can't control the child nodes further down, the way I want.

```
    for tree={
        fill=Red!100,
        l sep=2em,
        s sep=5pt,
        minimum height=3em, 
        minimum width=9em, 
        text=white,
        align=center,
        rounded corners, 
        },
```

Is there a way to lock the node with "0.2em lower than text" or something like that?

Comment: You could add `execute at begin node={\strut}, execute at end node={\strut},` to the option list for `for tree`. This will insert a `\strut` before and after the text in each node.

Comment: @JasperHabicht That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `execute at begin node={\strut}, execute at end node={\strut},` to the option list for `for tree`. This will insert a `\strut` before and after the text in each node which will help with vertical alignment of the text.

Please always provide a *compilable* MWE such as the following:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        edge label={
            node[above, fill=white, yshift=2mm, font=\footnotesize]{100\%}
        },
        fill=red!100,
        l sep=3em,
        s sep=5pt,
        minimum height=3em, 
        minimum width=9em, 
        text width=9em,
        text centered,
        text=white,
        rounded corners, 
        tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
        execute at begin node={\strut},
        execute at end node={\strut},
    }, 
    forked edges,
%   Indsæt her: 
    [Company A \\ ~\\ Finland
    [Company X \\ ~\\ Denmark]
    [Company Y \\ ~\\ Norway]
    [Company Z \\ ~\\ Sweden]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]